# refresh multiple table columns every 10 seconds

Tags: php, ajax

I have a table of data which needs to be refreshed every 10 seconds without reloading the page. But only certain columns in the table need to be refreshed, not all the data in the table. Im writing the application in PHP. How can I do this? Is this the right scenario for using ajax long polling?

Comment: Use jquery and follow a few tutorials on ajax.

Comment: Use `setInterval()` to run the refresh function every 10 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need long polling when you need immediate refresh to the table. You said 10 sec is okay, so you do not need long pooling. Just use ajax async calls.